# Improve the undesirable empty line produced by docstrip

Tags: docstrip, doc

In my `.ins` file, I have this setup before `\generate`:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active%
\obeyspaces%
\gdef\copyright{%
\ds@heading% This is file... generated with the docstrip utility.

Copyright (C) ...
}%
\gdef\lppllicense{%

This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of the
LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this license or (at
your option) any later version. The latest version of this license is in

    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX version
2005/12/01 or later.
}%
\endgroup

\def\mypreamble{\copyright\lppllicense}
\usepreamble\mypreamble
```

The beginning of the generated file is then:

```
%%
%% This is file `projlib-math.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.

%% Copyright (C) ...
%% 
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of the
%% LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this license or (at
%% your option) any later version. The latest version of this license is in
%% 
%%     http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX version
%% 2005/12/01 or later.
%%
```

As you can see, there is an empty line on line 4. How can I make it begin with `%%` like the other lines?

Comment: I'd say `\ds@heading\MetaPrefix`

Comment: @Robert Thank you, that works!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in comment.